# How to read adsense URL in C# (the one that is shown on mouse over)

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, url, adsense

How do I read the URL which is shown when move your mouse over to Adsense link? I am trying to read it using Webbrowser control in C# but it is nowhere to be found in DocumentText. Seems like it is being displayed through Javascript so how can I read it?
Even GetElementById function doesn't return the required element id.

Two examples of such URL are:

http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=By4nW0cV2nGieB6e7.........

and

http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=l&ai=BgdDhR3M1L47d..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the library provided by CodeCentix to read iframes
http://codecentrix.blogspot.com/2008/02/when-ihtmlwindow2document-throws.html

Answer (score 0):

Google adsense is placed on a page by the inclusion of a script. that script then runs once the page has loaded and generates either an iframe, or markup diurectly in the page. just getting the page will not run the adsense, you have to run the actual javascript in the page first, and then examine the generated markup.

If you want to do this from c# you should use something like [javascriptdotnet](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) or similar. - Or spider the page in java and use Rhino.

Comment: Your last line says "you have to run the actual javascript in the page first, and then examine the generated markup"

Since I am using webbrowser control, shouldn't this control be already doing this? Because it's a complete web browser based on IE.

Comment: Hi I am not totaly familiar with the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control - does it run any scripts - you could test on a simple page with a simple script.  If it doesn't there is probably a method or property you can invoke to start it. If it does it may be that the google script is not running becuase it does not think it is a real browser - try setting the useragent string to a known browser, perhaps you need to accept cookies.  - Just a few pointers  - HTH